# Spring @Retryable - how to log when it is invoked?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I use `compile 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.2.RELEASE'`with `Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE`.

Configured to retry my method and it works well:

```
@Retryable(value = { IOException.class }, maxAttempts = 5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 500))
public void someMethod(){...}
```

How to output some specific message when retry occurs?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can register a `RetryListener`:

```
@Bean
public List<RetryListener> retryListeners() {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    return Collections.singletonList(new RetryListener() {

        @Override
        public <T, E extends Throwable> boolean open(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback) {
            // The 'context.name' attribute has not been set on the context yet. So we have to use reflection.
            Field labelField = ReflectionUtils.findField(callback.getClass(), "val$label");
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(labelField);
            String label = (String) ReflectionUtils.getField(labelField, callback);
            log.trace("Starting retryable method {}", label);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
            log.warn("Retryable method {} threw {}th exception {}",
                    context.getAttribute("context.name"), context.getRetryCount(), throwable.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public <T, E extends Throwable> void close(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
            log.trace("Finished retryable method {}", context.getAttribute("context.name"));
        }
    });
```

If you don't need to log from all 3 interception points, you can override `RetryListenerSupport` instead. For example:

```
@Bean
public List<RetryListener> retryListeners() {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    return Collections.singletonList(new RetryListenerSupport() {

        @Override
        public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(
                RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
            log.warn("Retryable method {} threw {}th exception {}",
                    context.getAttribute("context.name"), 
                    context.getRetryCount(), throwable.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As soon as I enable a bean implementing RetryListenerSupport, my @Retryable annotated methods stop being respected. Any ideas?

Comment: @bforcer Are there any other RetryListener beans in your project? Maybe they interfere with each other.

Comment: Nope, this is the only bean implementing RetryListener

Comment: For me the solution was to add RetryListener in the SpringBoot Configuration (Main class)

Comment: What is this special character  "val$label" ?   Is is this a  Spring SpEL ？ （ ReflectionUtils.findField(callback.getClass(), "val$label");）

Answer (score 11):

Looking through the code the `org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate` performs the retry logic for retrying the operations. This template only logs simple things like:

```
o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=0
o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=1
o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=1
o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=2
o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=2
o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=3
o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry failed last attempt: count=3
```

If you want to log the specific exception you could catch the exception log it and rethrow. Unfortunately as far as i can see there is no way to log custom messages within the framework.

Another method would be to shadow the actual interceptor responsible for the invocation of your method like `RetryOperationsInterceptor`, this is not advised however.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to check [RetryContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/RetryContext.html):

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 2, include = RuntimeException.class)
public void test() {
    log.info("test");
    if (RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount() > 0) {
        log.warn(RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext());
    }
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

> [RetryContext: count=1, lastException=java.lang.RuntimeException, exhausted=false]